# How would I connect a customView to main activity

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-custom-view, program-entry-point

I created one customView which is stored in the Layout directory folder. I want to use it (reference it) in main activities xml layout. I can't figure out how I would import my customView into main activity and its xml. This customView does not have its own code, its by itself. I have yet to figure out how to connect my CustomView to its own class.
Once I am able to use my customView in main activity I will be placing it inside a frameViewGroup.

p.s. Is connecting a customView to an activity similar to connecting a customView to its own class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the custom view you created is through code, for example:

```
package gr.example.app.ui.layouts

class MyView extends View {
   ....
}
```

then you have to use the full package name in this case

```
<gr.example.app.ui.layouts.MyView>
```

but if you created it as an xml (let's say its name is my_view.xml) inside the resources/layouts folder like so:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="verical">

.....

</LinearLayout>
```

then you have to use include inside your main_activity.xml like so:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_view" --this is optional, just another way to find the root view of layouts/my_view
    layout="@layouts/MyView"/>
```

Comment: do I use that in the main_activity.xml? When ever I type in <com. my custom view doesn't show up. Things like <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton  show up.

Comment: wait I think we may have had a misunderstanding, I'll update my answer